# JS TS apply decorator to all methods / enumerate class methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I would like to apply a decorator function to all methods within a class so I can replace:

```
class User {
    @log
    delete() {}

    @log
    create() {}

    @log
    update() {}
}
```

with

```
@log
class User {
    delete() {}
    create() {}
    update() {}
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create a class decorator and enumerate the properties on the target's prototype.

For each property:

1. Get the property descriptor.
2. Ensure it's for a method.
3. Wrap the descriptor value in a new function that logs the information about the method call.
4. Redefine the modified property descriptor back to the property.

It's important to modify the property descriptor because you want to ensure your decorator will work well with other decorators that modify the property descriptor.

```
function log(target: Function) {
    for (const propertyName of Object.keys(target.prototype)) {
        const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target.prototype, propertyName);
        const isMethod = descriptor.value instanceof Function;
        if (!isMethod)
            continue;

        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            console.log("The method args are: " + JSON.stringify(args));
            const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
            console.log("The return value is: " + result);
            return result;
        };

        Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, propertyName, descriptor);        
    }
}
```

**Base Class Methods**

If you want this to affect the base class methods as well, then you might want something along these lines:

```
function log(target: Function) {
    for (const propertyName in target.prototype) {
        const propertyValue = target.prototype[propertyName];
        const isMethod = propertyValue instanceof Function;
        if (!isMethod)
            continue;

        const descriptor = getMethodDescriptor(propertyName);
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            console.log("The method args are: " + JSON.stringify(args));
            const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
            console.log("The return value is: " + result);
            return result;
        };

        Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, propertyName, descriptor);        
    }

    function getMethodDescriptor(propertyName: string): TypedPropertyDescriptor<any> {
        if (target.prototype.hasOwnProperty(propertyName))
            return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target.prototype, propertyName);

        // create a new property descriptor for the base class' method 
        return {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: target.prototype[propertyName]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, for me it worked only when I replaced everywhere you wrote `target.prototype` to just `target`

Comment: @MaorRefaeli in this question the decorator is being put on the class so `target` is the class function and `target.prototype` is the class prototype. So if `target` is specified instead then it would look at the static methods rather than the instance methods that are found on the prototype. The code here might need to be changed if targeting ES2015 instead of ES5 though because getting the properties for ES2015 classes won't work with this way... regardless the prototype should be used.

Comment: You are right :) I forgot to mention I used it on a static class

Comment: Object.keys doesn't work when the compile target is not ES5.  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target.prototype) worked fine for me for every other target.

Answer (score 12):

For whomever stumbles upon this in the future:

I took inspiration in David's answer and created my own version. I later made it into a npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/decorate-all

In OP's scenario, it would be used like this

```
@DecorateAll(log)
class User {
    delete() {}
    create() {}
    update() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't feel like pulling additional dependencies, here's a simplified version of @Papooch's implementation

```js
function DecorateAll(decorator: MethodDecorator) {
    return (target: any) => {
        const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(target.prototype);
        for (const [propName, descriptor] of Object.entries(descriptors)) {
            const isMethod =
                typeof descriptor.value == "function" &&
                propName != "constructor";
            if (!isMethod) {
                continue;
            }
            decorator(target, propName, descriptor);
            Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, propName, descriptor);
        }
    };
}

function Throttle(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function () {
        console.log("throttle");
        return original.call(this);
    };
}

@DecorateAll(Throttle)
class SharedApiClient {
    async fetch1() {    }
    async fetch2() {    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for all methods defined in the decorated class itself. Is there a pretty way to also cover the methods of the base class of `Target`?

I could make it work by also considering `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype))`, but this seems a bit fragile to me