# How to apply a decorator to all class methods using class decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I'm using experimental typescript decorators to manage access control in express.

```js
class AccountController extends Controller {
  
  login(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const token = await this.model.login(email, password);
    return res.json({
      token
    });
  }

  @hasRole('ADMIN')
  list(req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.json({
      data: await this.model.findAll()
    });
  }
}
```

`hasRole` method decorator is working fine and I'm happy with it.

The `Controller` implements REST methods:

```js
class Controller {
  list(req: Request, res: Response) { // impl }
  get(req: Request, res: Response) { // impl } 
  create(req: Request, res: Response) { // impl }
  update(req: Request, res: Response) { // impl }
  delete(req: Request, res: Response) { // impl }
}
```

The problem is, I have to apply the same decorators to most of other controllers and I find it very repetitive. For example, `StockController` should allow access to only `MERCHANT` role, and I have to do something like the following:

```js
class StockController extends Controller {
  @hasRole('MERCHANT')
  list(req: Request, res: Response) { 
    return super.list(req, res);
  }
  @hasRole('MERCHANT')
  get(req: Request, res: Response) { 
    return super.get(req, res);
  } 
  @hasRole('MERCHANT')
  create(req: Request, res: Response) { 
    return super.create(req, res);
  }
  @hasRole('MERCHANT')
  update(req: Request, res: Response) { 
    return super.update(req, res);
  }
  @hasRole('MERCHANT')
  delete(req: Request, res: Response) { 
    return super.delete(req, res);
  }
}
```

This approach is not only dull and repetitive but also unsafe, because if I add a method to `Controller` and accidentally forget to add the method to child controllers, they will allow unwanted access.

I'd like to deal this problem with class decorator and use something like the following:

```js
@requireRole('MERCHANT')
class StockController extends Controller {}
```

However, from what I see in the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html):

> The class decorator is applied to the constructor of the class and can be used to observe, modify, or replace a class definition.

As far as I understand it, I cannot implement "method hook" in class decorators. Any suggestions?

For your information, `hasRole` decorator looks like the following:

```js
export function hasRole(role: string) {
  return function(target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(req: Request, res: Response) {
      const user = res.locals.user;
      if (user && user.hasRole(role)) {
        originalMethod.apply(this, [req, res]);
      } else {
        res.status(403).json({});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A method decorator wraps the method into a new function that calls the original method and can also do other things before or after that. A class decorator wraps the constructor. It is possible to write a class decorator that does what you need.

Comment: @axiac Thanks for suggestion. Please guide me by an example, I'm lost..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible by overriding class methods

```
function AttachToAllClassDecorator<T>(someParam: string) {
    return function(target: new (...params: any[]) => T) {
        for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target.prototype)) {
            // maybe blacklist methods here
            let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target.prototype, key);
            if (descriptor) {
                descriptor = someDecorator(someParam)(key, descriptor);
                Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, key, descriptor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically going through all methods (maybe add some logic around it for whitelisting/blacklisting some methods) and overriding with new method that has method decorator wrapped.

Here is basic example for method decorator.

```
function someDecorator(someParam: string): (methodName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => PropertyDescriptor {
    return (methodName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor => {
        let method = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function(...args: any[]) {
            console.warn(`Here for descriptor ${methodName} with param ${someParam}`);

            return method.apply(this, args);
        }

        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-G4Saq1IVfOU+ll3ML+j6Nb54m4qBHaXT6ewOp0u1rumTyL0xxh+wWfaPyhR5gMF4P4sNxxHHKCTHSpu5ncs3BwAN3QBBANHhao0TJDDDbHa7jd1xjAjicnU8iG8-iCVaV6zgxwcNhEE4ABgAJPaxeL9isAEmUKedrpoysQNhgjsQrlEiBP5upys3rN7MQTeiQZ9ODnQZxnAIHxTCwVYoWnRVDm1RFvyTQ8bnhTVVG1AABVAMGwPBCBIMhKGNMk2BwNooG4AByQ1HRtciFFUCB8PIcJSMXDR1mkLZySxQ5qPIBwoFIrhoJGXj+NIgAmITkPVVQEWcEAFhgCBEAEqQhLjBFYM0eTFOU1SoEkoZNNk6IdJWPTSIAZlHDtyG7VDZPYlTSNkKRvAgOZ7msOwSLUuEgA)

Comment: Just to make it clear, `Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, key, descriptor);`. This line overwrites the decorator attached to the method. Correct?

Comment: That overrides the current method in class (one with no decorator), with method that has method decorator attached.

descriptor = someDecorator... attaches decorator to method

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. By the way, your code has a bug: `return method.apply(this, ...args);` will throw `CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object` error if a class method receives a param. You need to remove `...`, that is `method.apply(this, args)`

Comment: True, just wrote it from my head without really properly testing it :)

Comment: Updating playground url as well

Comment: NOTE: this apprach does not work for extended methods. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47621528/11792577