# How to Get the list of function names executed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Get the list of function names executed. This is king of logging the function name. I want to get the list of all executed functions in sequence.

Technologies: Angular2+, TS, JS

Sample code(Ignore syntaxes, below code is for sample purpose):

**1. component1 contains method call as below**

```
    count = 0;
    ngOnInit(){}
    add(): void{
        this.count++;
        service.shareData(this.count);
    }
    substract(): void{
        this.count--;
        service.shareData(this.count);
    }
```

*html page of this component contains two buttons:*

```
    <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
    <button (click)="substract()">Substract</button>
```

**2. component2 contains method call as below**

```
    count = 0;
    ngOnInit(){}
    getDataFromService(): void{
        this.count = service.getData();
    }
```

*html page of this component contains one buttons:*

```
    <button (click)="getDataFromService()">GetDataFromService</button>
```

**3. tempService contains the data from components**

```
    sharedCount: number;
    shareData(count): void{
        this.sharedCount = count;
    }
    getData(): number {
        return this.sharedCount;
    }
```

If the sequence of button click as below:

1. add
2. add
3. getDataFromService
4. add
5. substract
6. add
7. getDataFromService

Excepted functions calls/logs of this sequence of button click in below format:

```
[comp1] add
[tempService] shareData
[comp1] add
[tempService] shareData
[comp2] getDataFromService
[tempService] getData
[comp1] add
[tempService] shareData
[comp1] substract
[tempService] shareData
[comp1] add
[tempService] shareData
[comp2] getDataFromService
[tempService] getData
```

Expected output is to logged the sequence of functions call, but expecting the implementation as below,

1. We can use any other service/module/npm/any other way by using which output of function trace/logs.
2. We cannot add any console.log or function which can log the function calls. If we use this way here it may be the case, if we forgot to add console.log or function to log it. We will miss this function call logs.

I have checked below options, but not found exact way to log it.

1. Use service workers: looking for any event call which can listen any function call and track it.
2. Use any BOM or DOM feature, so that we can track function calls from here.
3. Any new factory or module.

Comment: I would use a TS decorator to apply logging logic to all of the component's methods. then aggregate all calls in one array.

see an example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621364/js-ts-apply-decorator-to-all-methods-enumerate-class-methods